# Extract all constants out of angular cache

Tags: angularjs, caching, constants

I know i can use `$injector.has('<constant name>')` to get a constant by name but the problem is i don't know the name ahead of time, i just want to get a list of all angular constants that (for example) start with "json_".  The reason i need this is because i'm building a module that people can plugin to their own code, this is why i won't know the names ahead of time but i can at least ask the programmer to start the constants i need to work with, with "json_".  Currently i have to tell them to name their constants exactly "json1", "json2", "json3", etc and this is bad because the user has to keep track of where they are in numbering and it's not good design.  There doesn't seem to be anything directly within the API's to do what i'm trying to do.

Comment: You should not rely on constants that you do not know of in your module. What you are describing sounds like a bad architecture.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it's not my module.  I'm expecting the programmer to add json_whatever constants in their own angular app.  See [this](http://plnkr.co/3H1kgFKWsr341zsWLZvp) Plunker.

Comment: This makes it incredibly easy for the programmer to add json files to their project, it prevents them from having to use 3rd party plugins to save json files directly to storage especially when programming for mobile apps.  Furthermore, i don't want the programmer to have to embed json directly within their code, this is ugly as well.  I feel, creating these independent little json1.js constant files is the most simple, straight forward approach unless someone has a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to get all constants in an angular module, but you can achieve this by loop through `_invokeQueue` which an internal using array to hold all registered services on a given angular module. If you registered a constant called `json_obj` in `angular.module('app')`, then in `angular.module('app')._invokeQueue` should contain an array like:

`['$provider', 'constant', ['json_obj', valueObj]]`

So you can get a list of `json_*` constants by:

```
function getJsonConstants(){ 

    var queue = angular.module('myApp')._invokeQueue;

    var jsonConstant = [];

    angular.forEach(queue, function(item){

        if(item[1] === 'constant'){
             if(item[2][0].match(/\bjson_/gi)){
                 jsonConstant.push({
                    key: item[2][0],
                    value: item[2][1]
                 })
             }
        }

    })

    return jsonConstant;

}
```

One more thing, this function can only return all constant registered in `angular.module('myApp')`, if `myApp` has any dependent modules, you should loop all _invokeQueue in those modules to get completed constant list.